# Combine two MsgBoxStyles in one with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, styles

I'm trying to create a `MsgBox()` that has both the `MsgBoxStyle.Critical` style and the `MsgBoxStyle.RetryCancel` button style. What I've tried so far is this:

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
    Dim Answer as MsgBoxResult
        Answer = MsgBox("Error", MsgBoxStyle.RetryCancel & MsgBoxStyle.Critical, _
        "Some sort of error.")
    If Answer = MsgBoxResult.Retry Then
        'REM: Try code again
    Elseif Answer = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

This is what the buttons currently look like:

[image: Should be Retry/Cancel]

There is no `Critical` icon on the message box.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `MessageBox` instead of `MsgBox`. Try this:

```
    Dim _result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to retry", "Confirm Retry", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    If _result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry Then
        ' try again code
    Else

    End If
```

[image: MessageBox Sample]

Answer (score 11):

Bitwise "combine" is called `Or`.

```
MsgBoxStyle.RetryCancel Or MsgBoxStyle.Critical
```

---

`MsgBoxStyle.RetryCancel & MsgBoxStyle.Critical` evaluates to `"5" + "16"`, which evaluates to `"516"`, which evaluates to `516`, which magically equals `MsgBoxStyle.YesNo Or MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton3` and is therefore interpreted as such.

Don't use the string concatenation operator `&` for bitwise logic.

Answer (score -1):

Using msgbox: Instead of the & use + sign, e.g.

```
MsgBoxStyle.RetryCancel + MsgBoxStyle.Critical
```

should work,  you could also try just the number so 5 (RetryCancel) + 16 (Critical) = 21. e.g.

```
MsgBox("Error", 21, "Some sort of error.") should work.
```

---

```
msgboxStyle codes:
OKOnly  = 0
OKCancel = 1
AbortRetryIgnore = 2
YesNoCancel = 3
YesNo = 4
RetryCancel = 5
Critical = 16
Question = 32
Exclamation = 48
Information = 64
DefaultButton1 = 0
DefaultButton2 = 256
DefaultButton3 = 512
```

Comment: It is a very bad advice to replace the constants [with their numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/11683).